# How to reference application settings with Razor syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to embed the value of Properties.Settings.Default.PreloadGlyph into the mark up of _splash.cshtml in an MVC4 application.

Alas, insertion into this inline JavaScript does not work

```
    spinnerGif.setAttribute("src", "@MyAppNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.PreloadGlyphUrl");
```

because the IDE reports that

> 'MyAppNamespace.Properties.Setting.Default' is inaccessible due to its
>   protection level.

It's certainly in scope in the controller that requested the view. This is a simplified version of the Index() method.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var psd = Properties.Settings.Default;
  return View();
}
```

How do I get `psd` into the context for the view, so I can do something like this?

```
spinnerGif.setAttribute("src", "@psd.PreloadGlyphUrl");
```

Comment: What is wrong with passing it in the model, tempdata, or viewdata?

Comment: What model? That's more or less the question, really. This is a spa app, MVC defines exactly two views, one is index.cshtml and the other is _splash.cshtml and all they do is show a spinner and load my Durandal app. `View()` is some kind of built in thing, I didn't write it, it was provided by the project template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The views are compiled into separate assemblies dynamically when you refresh any page.

This means that properties on your model need to be public. I presume one of the properties here `Properties.Settings.Default.PreloadGlyph` must be internal or private hence the fact you can't access it from the view assembly.

Unfortunately you can't use the InternalsVisbleToAttribute here because the assembly is dynamic and you can't tell what it'll be called, therefore the only option realistically is to make your property public (or copy the values to an object with public properties)

I have seen some code which accesses non-public properties using reflection (or a dynamic wrapper which under the hood uses reflection). This may also be an option

Why not create a viewmodel for passing the required data to your view.. You can set `MyAppNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.PreloadGlyphUrl` on that and pass it to your view using

```
return View(new ViewModel { PreloadGlyphUrl = MyAppNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.PreloadGlyphUrl});
```

Then you can access the proprety:

```
@Model.PreloadGlyphUrl
```

from the model

Comment: Aha! This is what I needed to know. Not being able to find anything defining a view model really had me confused. I shall try this forthwith.

Comment: Very good. The key insight is that View really ought to be named ViewRender and can be called without passing a model for static content, which is what was going on here. Having realised that this is actually a special case, and more normally a view-model would be created and passed, things become trivially easy.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out

Answer (score 4):

You could just create a new HtmlHelper like that:

HtmlExtensions.cs

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static string GetPreloadGlyphUrl(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        return Properties.Settings.Default.PreloadGlyphUrl;
    }
}
```

Page.cshtml

```
    <h2>@Html.GetPreloadGlyphUrl()</h2>
```